# Read an xml file from non-web project in C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read an xml file that is present in one of the projects in my VS solution. Here's my code.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Resources\XmlDocument.xml");

XDocument document = XDocument.Load(path);
```

This works fine if my xml file is in the web project. But in reality I have my xml file in a different project under the same solution.

I cannot use `Server.MapPath` as this searches web project. I searched for an answer but did not find any solution that worked for me.

How can I access this xml file? I am trying to access this from a helper method in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  string path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + (some path);


   public void LoadXML()
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
            lock (new object())
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    return (List<int>)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is working for me.

Comment: The problem that the OP has is the XML file isn't being copied into the base project.

Comment: Kristina, I tried your solution, but HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath still returns the path to web project.

Comment: Adding some more info, for the xml file properties, I have build action 'Embedded Resource' and  for copy to output directory I have tried with both  'Copy always' and 'Do not copy'

Comment: Yes, but you can change path if you know where is located your project, and if the path is not changing dynamically.

Comment: Hi Kristina, that suggestion worked. I manually changed the path in my code,

Comment: Great, you can even split that path by ("\\"), and you will get every Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your current directory, why not just navigate up a number of parent directories and then locate your file?

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
DirectoryInfo parent = info.Parent.Parent;
string file = Path.Combine(parent.FullName, @"your\path");
```

Here I use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get where the program is at now, but you can stack as many `Parent` elements as you need. Then you can combine the path to get to your file in the other project.

**EDIT:**

Once your application is running all the environment variables and `Server.MapPath` will give you the location that it is executing from (i.e. the path you are getting now). In light of this it may be easier to create a folder and reference this via it's full path. `(C:\Data\myfile.xml)`

Comment: Hi, I tried this , so Environment.CurrentDirectory returns C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express and not path to the project . Not sure what I am missing here

Comment: @Sri see my edit. Not sure what other options there may be for you